# How to create equi-distant labeled nodes and edges on a spiral with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-graphs

I used the code below and got figure 1. How do I get figure 2?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=white] circle [radius=4pt] (0,0) \foreach \t in {0.1,0.2,...,1.6}{
++({sqrt(\t)*700}:1.0cm) circle [radius=4pt]
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You can get figure 2 by adding numbers to the nodes and drawing arrows between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use nodes, you can name them and write in them.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, fill=red, minimum size=8pt, draw, text=white, font=\tiny}]
  \draw [fill=white] circle [radius=4pt] (0,0) \foreach \t in {0.1,0.2,...,1.6}{ ++({sqrt(\t)*700}:1.0cm) circle [radius=4pt] };
  \begin{scope}[xshift=50mm]
    \draw (0,0) node (n1) [my node] {1}  \foreach \t [count=\c from 2] in {0.1,0.2,...,1.6} { ++({sqrt(\t)*700}:1.0cm) node (n\c) [my node] {\c} };
    \graph [use existing nodes] {
      n1  -> n2 -> n3;
      n4 -> n6;
      n5 -> n15;
      n7 -> n17;
      n8 <- n10;
      n11 -> n13
    };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: spot the difference]

I suggest making them larger, however, as I had to use `\tiny` to fit the numbers, which is not going to be at all easy to read - especially with white on red.

Comment: Thanks! How do I change the color of some edges?

Comment: @Alvaro Check the syntax of the `\graph` command in the Ti*k*Z manual. In simple cases, you can probably add it straight in, as you would anywhere else. In more complex cases, things are trickier, but the cases you have should all be straighforward enough.